# Moving between Activities

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, android-activity

I have couple of activities. On the `mainActivity` I have 4 buttons each leads to another activity.
On three of the activities I activate a thread which draws in a canvas and in each of them I have a button to return to the `mainActivity`. I have tried using:

```
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                // i tried also (theClassName.this,MainActivity.Class)
                startActivity(i);
```

When I clicked on the return button, I did return to the `mainActivity` but the app stopped responding (it alerted me that the app isn't responding and I had to choose between waiting or exiting the app. Waiting doesn't help).

When I used

```
finish();
```

instead,

And clicked on the return button, I returned to the home screen of the device (went out of the app) but didn't exit it - I could still go back to the app using the task manager, and when I did it put me back in the activity I entered and not the `mainActivity`.

As I said I have 4 buttons on the `mainActivity` and when I use the fourth one it goes to another activity that doesn't activate a thread, it only has listView, and when I return from it to the mainActivity it does work.

How can I fix it? Thanks for the help

*when the problem occurs there is no error stack trace.

*if you need to see any code tell and I'll be happy to post it here

The code:

MainActivity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button classic;
    Button vsPlayer;
    Button vsComp;
//  Button settings;
    Button scores;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        classic=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Classic);
        classic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ClassicActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
        });

        vsPlayer=(Button) findViewById(R.id.PlayerVSPlayer);
        vsPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,VsPlayerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
        });

        vsComp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.PlayerVSComp);
        vsComp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,VsCompActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
        });

       /* settings=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Settings);
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
        });
*/
        scores=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Scores);
        scores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScoresActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
        });

    }//onCreate

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mains, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }

}
```

-=------  some other activity:

```
 public class ClassicActivity extends Activity  {
    Classic g;

    ImageView left;
    ImageView right;
    ImageView up;
    ImageView down;

    TextView pause;
    TextView back;

    TextView scoretv;

    LinearLayout surface;

    LinearLayout screen;

    LinearLayout stoped;
    LinearLayout gameover;

    ScoreDataSource sds;

    Button no;
    Button yes;
    EditText name;
    Button continueb;
    Button leave;

     //protected static TextView MyScore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        v= new GameView1(this);
        setContentView(v);
        */

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_classic);
        sds=new ScoreDataSource(this);
        gameover=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameover);
        screen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen);
        surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
        g= new Classic(this, surface);
        surface.addView(g);

        //MyScore=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyScore);
        //MyScore.setText("My score:"+gv.getPoints());

        left=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left);
        right=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right);
        up=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.up);
        down=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.down);

        left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(g.snake.getDir()!="LEFT"&&g.snake.getDir()!="RIGHT"){
                g.snake.Left();
                }
            }
        });
        right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(g.snake.getDir()!="RIGHT"&&g.snake.getDir()!="LEFT"){
                g.snake.Right();    
                }
            }
        });
        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(g.snake.getDir()!="UP"&&g.snake.getDir()!="DOWN"){
                g.snake.Up();   
                }
            }
        });
        down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(g.snake.getDir()!="DOWN"&&g.snake.getDir()!="UP"){
                g.snake.Down();
                }
            }
        });

        pause=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Pause);
        back=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Back);

        stoped=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stoped);

        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(g.getRunning()){
                    pause.setText("continue");
                    g.setRunning(false);
                }
                else{
                    pause.setText("pause");
                    g.setRunning(true);
                    new Thread(g.snakethread).start();
                }

            }
        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                g.setRunning(false);
                stoped.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        no=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no);
        yes=(Button) findViewById(R.id.yes);
        continueb=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Continue);
        leave=(Button) findViewById(R.id.leave);

        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String date = df.format(c.getTime());

                sds.open();
                Score s=new Score(0,name.getText().toString(),date, g.getPoints(),"Classic");
                s=sds.createScore(s);
                sds.close();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        continueb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stoped.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                g.setRunning(true);
                new Thread(g.snakethread).start();
            }
        });
        leave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        scoretv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoretv);

        screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(g.getGameover()){
                    scoretv.setText("Your score is:"+g.getPoints());
                    gameover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    g.setGameover(false);
                }
                }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

----ClassicActivity usus this activity:

```
    public class Classic extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    private boolean isRunning=false;
    private final long FPS=8;//MAX is 16
    final float scale = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float PART_SIZE= 10*scale;

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    Thread snakethread;
    static SnakePlayer snake;
    Arena a;
    LinearLayout view;
    Bitmap arena;
    Food food1;

    Boolean gameover;

    int points;
    Paint writePB=new Paint();
    Paint writePR=new Paint();



    public Classic(Context context,LinearLayout view) {
        super(context);
        this.gameover=false;
        this.view=view;
        this.a=new Arena(view,PART_SIZE,33,36,1,0);
        this.food1=new Food(PART_SIZE,"GRAY");
        points=0;
        writePB.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        writePB.setTextSize(PART_SIZE);
        writePR.setColor(Color.RED);
        writePR.setTextSize(PART_SIZE);
        snakethread=new Thread(this);
        holder= getHolder();

        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
                setRunning(true);
                snakethread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {



            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

                setRunning(false);

                while(true){
                    try {
                        snakethread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    });
        snake=new SnakePlayer(0+3*PART_SIZE, 0+3*PART_SIZE, "RIGHT",PART_SIZE,2,"RED","BLACK");
}

    @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        a.onDraw(c);
        c.drawText("Your Score:"+points, 5*scale, 10*scale, writePB);
        food1.drawFood(c);
        snake.onDraw(c);
    }
    @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
    @Override

    public void run() {
        long stepPerSecond=1000/FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        Canvas c = null;
        while(isRunning){
            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            c = null;
            try{
                c=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                onDraw(c);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
            finally{
                if(c!=null){
                    this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            AllChecks(c);
            sleepTime= stepPerSecond-(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
            if(sleepTime>0)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        if(gameover){
            try{
                c=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                c.drawText("GAMEOVER", 125*scale, 150*scale, writePR);
                c.drawText("Touch Anywhere To Continue ", 87*scale, 162*scale, writePR);
                }
            catch(Exception e){                 
            }
            finally{
                if(c!=null){
                    this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    boolean firstTime=true;
    public void AllChecks(Canvas c){
        /*
         * Call all the right function, to check if the snake has bumped in a wall, or eaten a food.
         */
        if(Arena.WallCollision(snake.getxLoc(), snake.getyLoc())){
            setRunning(false);
            gameover=true;
        }
        if(snake.snakeCollisionNoHead(snake.getxLoc(), snake.getyLoc())){
            setRunning(false);
            gameover=true;
        }
        if(firstTime){
            firstTime=false;
            changeFoodLoc(food1);
        }
        if(food1.hasEaten(snake.getxLoc(), snake.getyLoc())){
            changeFoodLoc(food1);
            snake.Add();
            points+=10;
        }
    }
    public void changeFoodLoc(Food food){
        /*
         * if a snake has eaten a food it changes the location of the food randomly
         */
        Random rnd = new Random();
        food.x=(rnd.nextInt(32) + 3)*food.SIZE;
        food.y=(rnd.nextInt(35) + 1)*food.SIZE;
        if(snake.snakeCollision(food.getX(), food.getY()))
            changeFoodLoc(food);    
    }
    public void setRunning(boolean b){
        isRunning=b;
    }
    public Boolean getRunning(){
        return isRunning;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public Boolean getGameover() {
        return gameover;
    }

    public void setGameover(Boolean gameover) {
        this.gameover = gameover;
    }   




}
```

Comment: can you post your logcat and see what the error is?

Comment: there are no errors in the logcat, you still want me to post it?

Comment: hahaha no, usually when you get that kind of error though it's because there is something is running and is taking too long to finish so you get that Application Not Responding error. ANR.

can you try to comment out your threading code to see if you still get this error? at least then you can narrow it down to the thread. You probably have to stop the thread when you are leaving the activity

Comment: The thread is stopped when i leave the activity, i mean that it exist the run function and only then there is an option to leave the activity

Comment: alright that is surprising,i commented out my threading code as you suggested and it still did the same problem. now i am clue less

Comment: what about the runnable code in surfaceview? try to scale back the code and see if that still has the ANR to show.

Answer (score 1):

First I would try removing the override on the MainActivity for onPause - you do not need to call finish. In your second activity, if you want to go back to the MainActivity- call finish on the 2nd activity and it should go back to the MainActivity.